# Fabric Composer test code not working

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I´ve just replaced the Composer default sample ("sampleAsset", "sampleTransaction", etc) by another one I created, for my better understanding.  Everything works except for the transaction, which return me the error message: 
"**Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction org.acme.sample.CompraDoVinho#**2b2d0624-bc..."

Find below the source codes:

> Blockquote

### Model file:

namespace org.acme.sample

asset Vinho identified by IDvinho {

```
o String IDvinho
--> Participante owner
o String uva
o String nomeVinho 
o Integer preco
```

}

participant Participante identified by IDparticipante {

```
o String IDparticipante
o String tipo
o String nomeEmpresa
```

}

transaction CompraDoVinho identified by IDcompra {

```
o String IDcompra
--> Vinho asset
o Integer precoVenda
```

}

### Logic:

function onSampleTransaction(CompraDoVinho) {

```
CompraDoVinho.asset.preco = CompraDoVinho.precoVenda;

return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.Vinho')

    .then(function (assetRegistry) {

        return assetRegistry.update(CompraDoVinho.asset);

  });
```

}

### Permissions:

rule Default {

```
description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
participant: "ANY"
operation: ALL
resource: "org.acme.sample"
action: ALLOW
```

}

> Blockquote

Could anybody help me finding where is the bug in my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The issue is almost certainly because you've renamed the transaction. Composer has 2 mechanisms to route transactions to JS functions:

1. (Legacy) using an `onMyTransactionType` naming convention. I.e. the function will be called when an instance of `MyTransactionType` is submitted.
2. (Preferred) using the `@transaction` and `@param` annotations. See below for an example. The `@transaction` annotation indicates that the function would like to process transactions and the `@param` annotation is used to specify the type of the transaction to process.

```
    /**
     * Place an order for a vehicle
     * @param {org.acme.vehicle.lifecycle.manufacturer.PlaceOrder} placeOrder - the PlaceOrder transaction
     * @transaction
     */
    function placeOrder(placeOrder) {
        console.log('placeOrder');

        let factory = getFactory();
        let NS = 'org.acme.vehicle.lifecycle.manufacturer';

        let order = factory.newResource(NS, 'Order', placeOrder.transactionId);
        order.vehicleDetails = placeOrder.vehicleDetails;
        order.orderStatus = 'PLACED';
        order.manufacturer = placeOrder.manufacturer;

        // save the order
        return getAssetRegistry(order.getFullyQualifiedType())
            .then(function (registry) {
                return registry.add(order);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Interesting.  I was not aware of such convention rule.  I´ve just replaced "CompraDoVinho" for "onSampleTransaction", but it´s still not working.  Any other thought?  Thanks by now.

Comment: I think it should be onCompraDoVinho, however much better to go with the annotation approach

Comment: I had the same problem. I made a new transaction called "Sell" and I didn't change the `@param` from *trade* to *sell*. `@param {org.acme.mynetwork.Sell}`   Having the `@param` in what appears to be comments is very misleading.

Comment: @Dan What is getFactory() method?

Comment: getFactory is used to create instances of assets, participants, transactions, events etc.

Comment: Hi i am just trying to create demo but i am getting below error :- 

Error: Could not find any functions to execute for transaction org.acme.mynetwork.Trade#4dbcc76f-332b-4a68-8606-8d9a510e1284

But i am following the official tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. The annotation is essential for the function to work!
@param must state the class name of the transaction and the param name
@transaction declared underneath, with function to follow in block below

@param {org.acme.mynetwork.Foo} foo - the report to be processed
 * @transaction

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace the code in your `logic.js` file with following code and the error will surely be gone. Mine was the same problem, I just added the required `JS doc annotations` above the function and the same issue was resolved!

```
'use strict';
var NS = 'org.acme.sample';
/**
 * @param {org.acme.sample} CompraDoVinho 
 * @transaction
 */
function onSampleTransaction(CompraDoVinho) {

CompraDoVinho.asset.preco = CompraDoVinho.precoVenda;

return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.Vinho')

    .then(function (assetRegistry) {

        return assetRegistry.update(CompraDoVinho.asset);

  });
}
```

Hope this helps you!